# One series converges iff the other converges

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

In [Show that $\sum\limits_pa_p$ converges iff $\sum\limits_{n}\frac{a_n}{\log n}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458492/show-that-sum-limits-pa-p-converges-iff-sum-limits-n-fraca-n-log-n-c) it is said that this sequence of  partial sums converges
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{1<n\leq N}\frac{a_{n}}{\log\left(n\right)} &=\sum_{1<n\leq N}1\cdot\frac{a_{n}}{\log\left(n\right)} \\
& =\frac{\left(N-1\right)a_{N}}{\log\left(N\right)}+\sum_{k\leq N-1}\left(k-1\right)\left(\frac{a_{k}}{\log\left(k\right)}-\frac{a_{k+1}}{\log\left(k+1\right)}\right)
\end{split}
$$  iff this sequence of partial sums converges
$$\sum_{p\leq N}a_{p}=\pi\left(N\right)a_{N}+\sum_{k\leq N-1}\pi\left(k\right)\left(a_{k}-a_{k+1}\right)∼ \frac{Na_{N}}{\log\left(N\right)}+\sum_{k\leq N-1}\frac{k}{\log\left(k\right)}\left(a_{k}-a_{k+1}\right)$$ But I don't see why. I think this should be clear but I can't get it. Can someone explain? ($a_n$ is a non-increasing sequence of positive numbers.)

Comment: Where is a series in this question? I only see finite sums.

Comment: Obviously i mean the series that extend these 2 partial sums

Comment: If what you asked is not exactly what you meant, then you might as well edit it, rather than leaving people to look in the comments.

Comment: guys this is obvious...i ll change it but its completely obvious...

Comment: It seems easier to answer differently to the question you refer to. Would this be enough?

Comment: A corresponding post on [math.se]: [One series converges iff the other converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4438592)

Comment: Do you have response to the answer below?

Comment: I think you posted first , just for the sake of authenticity, but this is something like this solution right? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4439064/1050277

Comment: I think its the same  but you posted first, just there it is simpler. I found it a very nice solution... Just one question... we sure can change the summation like we did those 2 times right? its not  like a rearrangement, its just the same sum written differently right? I mean you are sure we can do that ?

Comment: @IosifPinelis   ??

Comment: (i) Yes, the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4439064 is the same as mine but with some details omitted there, including details on the second equality in the first display in the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4439064 and on the second display there. I had not seen that answer before seeing your comment, as I usually do not go to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: (ii) The interchanges of the order of summation are valid, because all the summands are nonnegative. This may be considered a special case of the Tonelli theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_functions .

Comment: OK, it is just the same sum written in a different way,  but not a rearrangement of  the series, right? Just for the information.

Comment: In "it is just the same sum written in a different way", I don't know what you mean by "it" or by "the same sum" or by "a different way". I also don't know what you mean by "a rearrangement" or by "**the** series". So, without understanding anything in the question in your latest comment, I cannot possibly answer it. As I said, the  interchanges of the order of summation are valid, as a special case of the Tonelli theorem. This should be quite enough for the validation of those interchanges, without employing various undefined terms such as "rearrangement" or pronouns such as "this" or "it".

Comment: Do you still have doubts about the validity of the interchanges of the order of summation, or any other concerns about the answer below?

Comment: I dont have any doubts and  it seemed right to me from the first moment. Just for  the information i wanted to make sure that this is not a series rearrangement/ permutation or whatever else you call it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) . I knew it as "rearrangement" of the series thats why i called it that way.

Comment: In the link as you can see you can "rearrange" some series(those that converge conditionally)  series in ways that the new series that occur form a different series in the sense that it can converge somewhere else or evendiverge or even  not converge at all. But i think that is different of what you did here , that I wanted to assure; that this interchange you did was not a rearrangement(as at the link) and that also you can do that interchange you did without knowing if the series converges or diverges(you just reffered something about positive ummands) .

Comment: So if you could answer , I sum up the questions i have here: (1) This interchange of the series you did (those 2 times ) is indeed NOT like that in the link i posted about the riemann theorem ? (2)You can do that interchange whenever you have positive summands , either if the series converges or diverges?-or even if you dont know if converges or diverges?- (3) You can not do that interchange if we havent positive summands?

Comment: PS That is why I called it "its the same sum just written differently", because -as I think - after the interchange you did the sum of the "new" series is the same(and it probably is just the same series, in the sense that the sums are the same either it is a real number or plus infinity) , while in the other rearrangement like at the link i posted it can be different. Thank you.

Comment: (1) No, the interchange of the order of summation is not the same as that kind of rearrangement of a series. (2) Yes, if the summands are nonnegative, you can interchange the order of summation, whether the resulting sum is finite or infinite. (3) If the summands are of different signs but the resulting sum of the **absolute values** of the summands is finite, then you can still interchange of the order of summation -- this is the Fubini theorem.

Comment: If this answers all your questions and you have no doubts about the answer, can we finalize this in accordance with the guidelines at https://mathoverflow.net/help/accepted-answer and https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers ?

Comment: OKK, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a_n$ is nonincreasing and nonnegative, $a_n$ converges to some real $a\ge0$. If $a>0$, then neither one of the two series converges. It remains to consider the case $a=0$. Then
\begin{equation*}
    a_n=\sum_{j\ge n}b_j  \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
for some nonnegative $b_j$'s.

By the prime number theorem,
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{k\le n} 1(k\in P)\sim \frac n{\ln n}\sim\sum_{k\le n}\frac1{\ln k}, \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
where $P$ is the set of all prime numbers.

In view of \eqref{1},
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \sum_p a_p&=\sum_n 1(n\in P)\,a_n \\ 
    &=\sum_n 1(n\in P)\,\sum_{j\ge n}b_j \\ 
    &=\sum_j b_j\sum_{n\le j} 1(n\in P). 
\end{aligned}   
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}

By \eqref{2},
\begin{equation}
    \sum_j b_j\sum_{n\le j} 1(n\in P)<\infty \iff 
    \sum_j b_j\sum_{k\le j}\frac1{\ln k}<\infty. 
    \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation}
But
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &\sum_j b_j\sum_{k\le j}\frac1{\ln k} \\ 
    &=\sum_k\frac1{\ln k}\sum_{j\ge k} b_j \\ 
        &=\sum_k\frac{a_k}{\ln k}. 
        \end{aligned}
        \tag{5}\label{5}    
\end{equation*}

It follows from \eqref{3}, \eqref{4}, and \eqref{5} that
\begin{equation}
    \sum_p a_p<\infty \iff 
\sum_k\frac{a_k}{\ln k}<\infty, 
\end{equation}
as desired.

Comment: Did you answer the OP's question?

Comment: @mathworker21 : I think the question was, basically, how to use the prime number theorem to show that the two series converge/diverge simultaneously, and I answered that question. The linked answer on Math SE does not seem to be written quite well, as the standard symbol $\sim$ does not seem to be used correctly there, which possibly created the OP's confusion. Frankly, I did not read the linked Math SE answer till just now and, mea culpa, I did not even read the question in the OP very carefully. Anyhow, now there is a seemingly correct proof. :-)